# How to use default bootstrap class with styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, styled-components

I want to use bootstrap's `display-4` class within the styling of a `styled-component`.

The `styled-component`:

```
const Heading = styled.h2`
        font-weight: bold,
        color: #968c8c,
`;
```

Where do I put the `display-4` bootstrap class in the `styled-component`. I know I could do `className='display-4'` every time I use the `Heading` component, but surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [attrs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs) to set prop values.

> This is a chainable method that attaches some props to a styled
> component. The first and only argument is an object that will be
> merged into the rest of the component's props.

```
const Heading = styled.h2.attrs(() => ({
  className: 'display-4',
}))`
  font-weight: bold,
  color: #968c8c,
`;
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! I also added `font-weight-bold` to the `className`, for some reason the `font-weight` css property didn't work.